# binding a path from input tag to an instance variAble in my bean class

Tags: file, jsp, jsf, binding

I need to take a file from the user.

My JSP page has the `<input type="file">` tag.

The problem is when I try to bind the tag to an instance variable.

```
<input type="file" value= "#{bean.inputPath}">
```

bean being my registered managed bean and `InputPath` being my instance variable, it gives an error at run time.

I just need the path of the file in my variable, and not to upload the file. How can I achieve this?

---

Thanks fir the quick reply

Well the requirements are :

I need to develop a Web application for encrypting/decrypting a text file

The user needs to tell the application the path of the file.

Also the encryption algorithm needs to now the full path of the file for encryption.

I tried another thing in my jsp page

Script :

var filepath = document.getElementById('fileName').value ;

document.getElementById('fileHidden').value = filePath ;

But this isn't working.
This should work.
Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The browser won't send the full path of `<input type="file">` anyway. It would only send the file name. Only Microsoft Internet Explorer has a security bug that it sends the full file path instead of only the file name. But you should not let your web application depend on bugs of a specific webbrowser which is used by only 20% of the world.

But all with all this makes no sense. What exactly is the functional requirement for which you thought that it is the right solution? How is it ever useful for a server to have the complete file path of the client's disk file system without having the complete file content? If you elaboarate the concrete functional requirement in more detail, we may be able to propose the right solution for that.